# Deleting UIPicker Data

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uipickerview

We are trying to delete data from a UIPicker view upon selection, however, it is deleting only the first string "Select You're Time" upon election of any string in UIPicker. After going back, "Select You're Time" is also reloaded. The reload function is required otherwise our code doesn't delete anything.

```
 import Foundation
 import UIKit
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseDatabase

 class timeSinglesViewController:UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!
     @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UITextField!

     var pickerData = ["Select You're Time","6:30", "7:30", "8:30", "9:30", "10:30", "11:30", "12:30", "1:30", "2:30", "3:30", "4:30", "5:30", "6:30", "7:30"]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         myPicker.dataSource = self
         myPicker.delegate = self
         myPicker.tag = 1


     }
     func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
         return 1
     }

     func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

         return pickerData.count

     }

     func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
         return pickerData[row]
     }

     func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
         myLabel.text = pickerData[row]

     }



     @IBAction func postData(sender: AnyObject) {
         let row = Int()
         let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("deleted url")
         ref.child("Time").setValue(myLabel.text)
         pickerData.removeAtIndex(row)
         myPicker.reloadAllComponents()
     }



}
```

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: As an aside - it should be 'Select Your Time'

Comment: When you say 'After going back' - do you mean another ViewController is pushed and then popped?

Comment: I am referring to going to the next view then clicking a back bar button item.

Comment: You are not storing pickerData in a persistent location, so the value maybe reset to the initial value.  You may need to create an object that stores session state, which you can query to see if "Select Your Time" has been show once - if so then don't show again.  The correct iOS terminology is going to the next 'ViewController'.